# Holographic geodesic derivation in AdS3 and BTZ

Tags: general-relativity, quantum-entanglement, conformal-field-theory, ads-cft, holographic-principle

I am trying to derive equation 2.4 in the article https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0603001
The AdS3 metric in global coordinates $(t,\rho,\theta)$ is given by
\begin{align}
ds^2=R^2(-\cosh^2\rho dt^2+d\rho^2+\sinh^2\rho d\theta^2)
\end{align}
where $R$ is the AdS radius. They introduce a cut-off $\rho_0$, s.t. $\rho\leq\rho_0$, with the relation for the total system length $L$ and lattice cut-off is $e^{\rho_0}=\frac{L}{a}$.
At the boundary $\rho_0$, they geometry is identified with a cylinder $(t,\theta)$, where $0\leq\theta\leq\frac{2\pi l}{L}$.
The static geodesic length $L_\gamma$ connecting the two points $0$ and $\frac{2\pi l}{L}$ is found to be
\begin{align}
\cosh\left(\frac{L_\gamma}{R}\right)=1+2\sinh^2\rho_0\sin^2\frac{\pi l}{L}.
\end{align}
I have trouble obtaining this relation, and wonder if there is some trick I am unaware of? Any hints/help are appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer in another article they've written https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0605073, section 6.2.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand even with this reference, I have calculated the length of the $\vec{X}$  but I get a function of $\rho$ and $\alpha$. Where does the $cosh$ in the LHS comes from?

Comment: It's been a while since I studied this formalism, but I believe it originates from the standard tensorial transformation propperties from the real surface $\bar{z}=z^*$ to a cylindrical geometry with holomorphic coordinates $w=e^{\frac{2\pi}{L}z}$. Remember, that the AdS/CFT correspondence is (loosely stated) equivalent to $Z_{CFT_2}=Z_{AdS_3}$.